# Unable to figure out problem with print statement

Tags: python, printing, error-handling

About the Program:

This program takes input length of integer and a integer and produces output the minimum possible sum that is possible after splitting the integer in two parts. You may find more details [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1181/problem/B).

```
n = int(input())
s = str(input())
j, i = n // 2, n // 2 + 1

# debug
# print(f'initial \n x = {j}, y = {i}')

while (j > 0 and s[j] == '0'):
    j-=1
while (i < n and s[i] == '0'):
    i+=1

# debug
# print(f'final\n x = {j}, y = {i}')

if j==0:
     print(int(s[0:i]) + int(s[i:n]))
     print('statement1')
elif i==n:
    print( int(s[0:j]) + int(s[j:n]))
    print('statement2')
else:
    print(min( int(s[:i])+  int(s[i:]), int(s[:j]) + int(s[j:])))
```

when I try input interger:

1. 7 and  1234567 - I am getting the correct output of 1801
2. 4 and 0001 - Correct output as well of 1

but when I try the inputs
**4** and **1000** program is throwing output *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''* whose cause I am unable to find out.

Comment: Have you tried printing just `s[0:i]` and `s[i:n]`, before casting them to `int`? It looks like either `i == 0` or `i == n` at some point there, and python has trouble casting an empty string to an integer

Comment: It's because the ending values of `i` and `j` are `0`, so the slice `s[:j]` is an empty string which is an invalid `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you the problem: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. This means that you are getting an empty string `""` as an argument for `int()`. In the code example you gave, this error will happen because `s[i:n]` returns `""` when `i` equals `n`.
You can check this debugging with this `print`:

```
print(f'final j = {j}, i = {i}, n = {n}, s = `{s}`')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if j==0:
    print(int(s[0:i]) + int(s[i:n]))
```

For inputs 4 and 1000, `i` and `n` are equal to 4.

This means that `s[i:n]` becomes `s[4:4]`, which is an empty string.  You can't call `int()` on an empty string.